# mysql insert new colum from other table

Tags: mysql

I have two table 
one is `xxx.goods` and one is `xxx.drp.good`.

inside the `xxx.goods` table as

```
cat_id
goods_sn
goods_name
goods_name_style
click_count
brand_id
provider_name
goods_number
goods_weight
market_price
shop_price
promote_price
promote_start_date
promote_end_date
warn_number
keywords
goods_brief
goods_desc
goods_thumb
goods_img
original_img
is_real
extension_code
is_on_sale
is_alone_sale
is_shipping
integral
add_time
sort_order
is_delete
is_best
is_new
is_hot
is_promote
bonus_type_id
last_update
goods_type
seller_note
give_integral
rank_integral
suppliers_id
is_check
```

at xxx.drp.goods table

```
goods_id
touch_sale
touch_fencheng
```

how can I add the columns `goods_id` `touch_sale` `touch_fencheng` in the `xxx.goods` table?

This is case, these two databases are the details of the product, but only xxx.drp.goods recorded the distribution amount of the goods. Whenever I fill in the distribution amount in the system backend, it just will be added to xxx.drp.goods. If I didn't add it, xxx.drp.goods would not have a distribution record for the product. As a result, I need to manually add the distribution amount one by one at the system backend.
database at xxx.goods contains all the details of the goods, except the distribution amount. Is there any way I can add the distribution amount on xxx.goods? And I just only modify all product distribution amounts bulk on mysql. Instead of entering the distribution amount of the product one by one in the system backend.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all of your 3 columns have numeric values.

I will show how to do it for 1 column ("goods_id"), you can copy and make the same way for the others. So here is the code:

```
ALTER TABLE xxx.goods ADD COLUMN goods_id TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
```

Then the second query:

```
UPDATE xxx.goods t1
INNER JOIN xxx.drp.goods t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
SET t1.goods_id = t2.goods_id;
```

Comment: i need some hlep bro.

Comment: @何浚弘 how can I help you?

Comment: @何浚弘 I read your question. What I understand is that you manually adding the information to the second database. What I advice you to do is create 1 different table where you will have all records, and query/put/delete/update all your information from there.